# How to send api key with axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I tried to get data from this api https://api.rajaongkir.com/starter/province and api key, i already put my api key correctly when requested the data. but the response was Invalid key.

here's my code :

[image]

here's the response

[image]
[image]

---

#### EDIT

i don't understand, it's ok if i use postman

[image]

Comment: i tried to resend the same request with same API key by proxy and i still get the same error , I think the problem from your API key ,

I hope this API key is for the purpose of the example

Comment: @KhaledNassar the API key **may** be wrong but here, the issue is ahead of the key verification, it's a CORS issue. As for Luke: having to run it on Postman is working because this is not considered as a frontend, hence it's fine. The query will work the same way if you do use it in a Node.js environment. The CORS issue is still here and you need to handle this one at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does not work is the prefligth request with 'OPTIONS' HTTP type.

This request is done directly by you browser.
A solution is to do the request on a NoeJS server and send back the data to the client.

You should not give your API key to the client anyway.

Comment: still got 400 error. i try to get data using postman with same api key. it works fine

Comment: @Luke ive found the issue, and rewrite completely the answer, it is because of the OPTIONS call done by your browser

Comment: The API key may be a public one as a lot of them nowadays. Even if a Node.js middleware may work, this is a workaround and whitelisting the client is still the way to go IMHO.

Comment: @CharybdeBE yes i shouldn't request on frontend. thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, I did the effort of typing your image code as text for you, here it is overall:

```js
console.log(
  'test',
  this.$axios.$get('https://api.rajaongkir.com/starter/province', {
    headers: { key: '00958fbcc8a7d31edf4bc2c168de705c' },
  }),
)
```

Next time, please provide it as text rather than image.

---

Also yeah, as [mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68620773/how-to-send-api-key-with-axios#comment121273185_68621358), you can see that the issue is actually a CORS issue.

[image]

To fix this properly, you need to whitelist your domain name and your localhost on Rajaongkir's dashboard somewhere.

PS: once the issue is fixed, I do recommend you to recreate a brand new API key since this one is now public.